# How to parse redis expire time from rdb?

Tags: java, redis

I save a key with expire(set name2 jack EX 3600) in redis and run command SAVE.
The ttl is about 3598521 before I run SAVE.

The bytes in rdb is fc22 611a ff5e 0100 00
How can I parse it to milliseconds in java?

Comment: I have tried the following way but I got the wrong result(1507518472482).<code>private long parseExpiry8Bytes() {
    return ((long)ts[7] & 0xff) << 56
         | ((long)ts[6] & 0xff) << 48
         | ((long)ts[5] & 0xff) << 40
         | ((long)ts[4] & 0xff) << 32
         | ((long)ts[3] & 0xff) << 24
         | ((long)ts[2] & 0xff) << 16
         | ((long)ts[1] & 0xff) <<  8
         | ((long)ts[0] & 0xff) <<  0;
  }<code>